# MATLAB:How to export data values into excel file

Tags: excel, matlab

```
pic1 = double (Pic1);
pic2 = double(Pic2);
pic3 = double(Pic3);
pic4 = double(Pic4);

ILB = 1;
B = pic1./ILB;

ILC = 0.2;
VC(1:1024,1:1024)= 0.581695;
VT = 0.025;
C = (pic2 - B*ILC)./(exp(VC./VT))

IL = 1;
V1 = VT*log((pic3 - B*IL)./(C));
V2 = VT*log((pic4 - B*IL)./(C));

Vapp1(1:1024,1:1024)=0.616185;
Vapp2(1:1024,1:1024)=0.575044;

jp = input('Please enter the jp value ranging between 36 to 40 mA/cm^2: ');
if jp >0

R =(((Vapp2-V2).*exp(V1./VT))-((Vapp1-V1).*exp(V2./VT)))./(jp.*(exp(V2./VT)-exp(V1./VT)))
imagesc(R)

j0 = ((Vapp2-V2-Vapp1+V1).*(jp))./(exp(V1./VT).*(Vapp1-V2)-exp(V2./VT).*(Vapp1-V1));
figure;
imagesc(j0)

end
```

I want to export the R and J0 data values shown in workspace respectively into an excel file or txt. file. What is the coding to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com you can use `csvwrite(filename,M)` to export variables to a csv file. Then you just have to import the file in Excel.

Try:

```
csvwrite('R_var.csv', R);
csvwrite('j0_var.csv', j0);
```

Comment: A .csv file is not an excel file, even though excel can still read theses. Worth trying with `xlswrite()` as well.

Comment: Due to @shoba asking for _an excel file or txt_ I chose a format which would work both on Excel and notepad(s). But the `xlswrite()` also does the job :)